# Problema com Lógica do If com GPS em Android

Tags: android, geolocalização

- **Como Funciona**:

> A latitude do GPS do usuário deve estar **entre -22.899529 e
>   -22.899922** para que se **crie** um **perímetro**. O aplicativo só vai funcionar algumas funcionalidades caso esteja dentro deste perímetro

.

- **Observação**:

> **1)** Eu não inseri a longitude pois estou tentando fazer com que ele
>   entre neste If, mas estou com uma grande díficuldade, caso for
>   possível por gentileza mostrar exemplos com o longitude juntos.

- **Shopping.java**

> ```
> package com.vuforia.samples.Books.app.Neoris;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
>
> import com.vuforia.Vuforia;
> import com.vuforia.samples.Books.ui.ActivityList.AboutScreen;
>
> /**
>  * Created by th on 14/06/17.
>  */
>
> public class Shopping {
>
>     private String nomeShopping;
>     private String licenseKey;
>     private String accessKey;
>     private String secretKey;
>
>     private Activity mActivity;
>     private int mVuforiaFlags = 0;
>
>     public Shopping(AboutScreen aboutScreen) {
>     }
>
>     public Shopping() {
>
>     }
>
>     public String getNome() { return nomeShopping; }
>
>     public void setNome(String nome) {
>         this.nomeShopping = nome;
>     }
>
>     public String getLicenseKey() {
>         return licenseKey;
>     }
>
>     public void setLicenseKey(String licenseKey) {
>         this.licenseKey = licenseKey;
>     }
>
>     public String getAccessKey() {
>         return accessKey;
>     }
>
>     public void setAccessKey(String accessKey) {
>         this.accessKey = accessKey;
>     }
>
>     public String getSecretKey() {
>         return secretKey;
>     }
>
>     public void setSecretKey(String secretKey) {
>         this.secretKey = secretKey;
>     }
>
>     public void setDados(double latitude, double longitude){
> //   -22.899529    -22.899922
>         // O menor é o MAIOR
>         // o maior é o MENOR
>         if((latitude >= -22.899529 && latitude <= -22.899922)){
>             setNome("Neoris");
>             setLicenseKey("Ad84Z0z/////AAAAGSgcOhPVvkoniWypHW2Dfsw+iX69sih5qx5JH1PEs92sM2xIhbsKnb2eTNkfBeQymsfgyRswpCDi2Ocu78RH+5+7/fXED7hJPLf3T7k4xKKLl4z8OKfCmr8jE0L5wQdJVV9L3tiHEoUx67M4b3ZSlO3/AzDLYi2/Zt3z8fuPo62osy469O+bKBsKKZtnyX9K7RYwJ2colMQ1bIhQERjg1w5cEZLHUacXAI1ndYhzS2Xl5iwAz98VZ65sptn+PrA5Xno55VGddt7rSBmvwuhZzeyShWnOqiYFhjWg80F3PFv2H/hYfIt4ML37yerJxS/n0z8yFv1H5gPi+Abd5nfaboz/xx1WgXf0yDvQKslFV+rr");
>             Vuforia.setInitParameters(mActivity, mVuforiaFlags, "" + getLicenseKey()); // Importante para o setLicenseKey.
>             setAccessKey("f854427b00cf89cb4909cf3780a22f1fe6dd1daa");
>             setSecretKey("16208b50224e2ff8d3c93f069d2c4adf739cea7a");
>
>         } else if((latitude >= -22.899682) && (latitude <= -22.900006) && (longitude >= -43.178666) && (longitude <= -43.178197)){
>             setNome("Outros");
>             setLicenseKey("AULCxLD/////AAAAGa6JoRhAAk70lshljOUpGeN7XUgbJ/jA8ZGpdHb4EVUBTsJ5Z6C8FYvrRBtMsbePU6wI2DKgO3U7msQ9bMqY1+qn0SRY8K3raNYxd+cgBkbmiJDonnuvPr9Hd3RHo7ArwO1x8wGsA1sWw/Bo+q7HpjLbdKqM/ceI2IlnWJQTD+H47zlFuV63utnK/soPttLP+HmL1Lx/ko6uLLKe9yhuuAwpbkNR0UsNGYXlueTCOU/CfIot0VCBg2Kxpz4/cnlmCetedW0+bZypzh6gWfV9MS1Sh9n1LEYr8EXjpOEyHhaBPAgE3lX5khkVc3FRetD81WC7fRAQB5ozp6X1H4u04yWLbzWf8S8XSPK5a542gbNg");
>             Vuforia.setInitParameters(mActivity, mVuforiaFlags, "" + getLicenseKey()); // Importante para o setLicenseKey.
>             setAccessKey("6ad29c13cb8af364c7c7f893ca7651974a887f96");
>             setSecretKey("370db33ce57acc73a84df1f6d19339da69e45235");
>
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```

- **AboutScreen.java** [O código não está completo, pois não precisa]:

> ```
>             latitude = gps.getLatitude();
>             longitude = gps.getLongitude();
>
>             /*
>             *  Melhora a precisão do Resultado encontrado pelo GPS
>             *  para (6) casas decimais com arredondamento.
>             * */
>             BigDecimal precisaoLatitude = new BigDecimal(latitude);
>             BigDecimal precisaoLongitude = new BigDecimal(longitude);
>             precisaoLatitude = precisaoLatitude.setScale(6, RoundingMode.UP);
>             precisaoLongitude = precisaoLongitude.setScale(6, RoundingMode.UP);
>
>             latitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(precisaoLatitude));
>             longitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(precisaoLongitude));
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

estava observando o seu código do if e notei o seguinte.

`latitude >= -22.899529 && latitude <= -22.89992`

Isso nunca vai entrar, pois para a latitude ser maior que -22.899529, você estaria esperando um latitude como -22.89952**8** e para ela ser menor que -22.89992 você precisaria de uma latitude como -22.8999**3**, então nenhuma latitude entraria no seu if.

O correto em minha opinião seria você inverter os sinais, sendo assim ficaria:

`latitude <= -22.899529 && latitude >= -22.89992`

Porque assim ficaria na faixa de "529" até "992", entendeu?

Comment: mas olha só neste meu raciocínio. -22.899529 é um número maior que -22.89992, pois este primeiro número está mais perto de ser positivo do que o outro, correto? Então ele não pode ser <= -22.899529 e nem >= -22.89992. Ou estou errado?

Comment: Está errado. Você quer que a posição esteja entre 2 valores: -xx.xxx920 e -xx.xxx529, então ela deve ser maior que -xx.xxx920 e menor que -xx.xxx529.

Comment: Mas então @ThiagoSaad, foi isso que respondi, latitude <= -22.899529 && latitude >= -22.89992. O seu está latitude >= -22.899529 && latitude <= -22.89992.

Comment: @VictorPettengillFernandes, ele não entra no if.. Eu li a API e diz para utilizar o Location.distanceBetween , porém ele só calcula  (Latitude do Usuario, Longitude do Usuario, latitude origem, latitude destino). Eu preciso que ele calculo 2 LAT e 2 LONG + a comparação da LAT e LONG do usuário.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira a resposta do Victor está correta. Como é número negativo, para números antes do -22.89992 são maiores mesmo.

Comment: Eu disse "Está errado" para o comentário acima do meu.

Answer (score 7):

Então galera, eu li a discusão e acredito que está tendo um equívoco por aqui.

Latitude/Longitude não deve ser comparada com maior ou menor, pois não são números, mas sim coordenadas.

Para delimitar um perímetro de coordenadas, você tem que não comparar entre as duas, mas sim determinar os bounds do lugar e ai sim comparar.

Esse bound tem que levar em consideraçao não somente uma parte da coordenada, mas sim a coordenada inteira (lat/long)

Um exemplo, tive um projeto onde tinha o ponto inicial da cidade, e depois tinha a área da cidade, e precisava saber se uma lat/long estava dentro da área da cidade. É mais ou menos essa a idéia o pedido do amigo, porém mais restrita a uma distância menor.

Até daria para verificar se a latitude/longitude está entre uma e outra, invertendo a ordem da consulta pois lat/long se mede da direita pra esquerda, a partir dos meridianos (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190923/is-a-lat-lon-within-a-bounding-box).

Então minha solução seria a seguinte:

1. Determinar o perimetro usando bounds, pela lat/long. Se for algum lugar, usuaria a consulta do google maps pra saber os bounds do estabelecimento, como referência https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990985/how-to-check-if-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-specific-address-belongs-to-lat-and
2. Criar os bounds, referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319431/how-to-convert-a-latlng-and-a-radius-to-a-latlngbounds-in-android-google-maps-ap
3. Depois verificar se a lat/long está dentro do LatLngBounds criado no 3, usando o método contains(LatLng), referência: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds;